# How install header files for opencv in C in my ubuntu 11.10

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, header

Resently I'm installed Opencv in my machine. Its working in python well(I just checked it by some eg programs). But due to the lack of tutorials in python I decided to move to c. I just run an Hello world program from http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/

My program is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  IplImage* img = 0; 
  int height,width,step,channels;
  uchar *data;
  int i,j,k;

  if(argc<2){
    printf("Usage: main <image-file-name>\n\7");
    exit(0);
  }

  // load an image  
  img=cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
  if(!img){
    printf("Could not load image file: %s\n",argv[1]);
    exit(0);
  }

  // get the image data
  height    = img->height;
  width     = img->width;
  step      = img->widthStep;
  channels  = img->nChannels;
  data      = (uchar *)img->imageData;
  printf("Processing a %dx%d image with %d channels\n",height,width,channels); 

  // create a window
  cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
  cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 100, 100);

  // invert the image
  for(i=0;i<height;i++) for(j=0;j<width;j++) for(k=0;k<channels;k++)
    data[i*step+j*channels+k]=255-data[i*step+j*channels+k];

  // show the image
  cvShowImage("mainWin", img );

  // wait for a key
  cvWaitKey(0);

  // release the image
  cvReleaseImage(&img );
  return 0;
}
```

first while compiling I got the following error

```
hello-world.c:4:16: fatal error: cv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

and I rectify this error by compiling like this

```
gcc -I/usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/CORE -o hello-world hello-world.c
```

But now the error is

```
 In file included from hello-world.c:4:0:
/usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/CORE/cv.h:14:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘_XPV_HEAD’
 hello-world.c:5:21: fatal error: highgui.h: No such file or directory
 compilation terminated.
```

Qns : 
     Is it this header is not installed in my system? While I'm using this command find /usr -name "highgui.h" I'm not find anything
     If this header is not in my sysytem hoew I install this?

Please help me . I'm new in opencv

Answer (score 4):

First check if highgui.h exists on your machine:

```
sudo find /usr/include -name "highgui.h"
```

If you find it on path lets say "/usr/include/opencv/highgui.h"
then use:

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h> in your c file.
```

or

while compiling you could add

```
-I/usr/include/opencv in gcc line
```

but then your include line in c file should become:

```
#include "highgui.h"
```

if, your first command fails that is you don't "find" highgui.h on your machine. Then clearly you are missing some package. To figure out that package name, use apt-find command:

```
sudo apt-find search highgui.h
```

on my machine, it gave me this:

```
libhighgui-dev: /usr/include/opencv/highgui.h
libhighgui-dev: /usr/include/opencv/highgui.hpp
```

if you don't have apt-find then install it first, using:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-find
```

So, now you know the package name, then issue:

```
sudo apt-get install libhighgui-dev
```

once this is done, use the find command to see where exactly, headers been installed and then use then change include path accordingly

Answer (score -1):

I have the following headers in my project:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
```

The version of OpenCV 2.4.2